# How to Set Up Chrome Headless on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere, google-chrome-headless

I'd like to set up Chrome in headless mode and the ChromeDriver for Selenium testing on my PythonAnywhere instance. I can't find any instructions on how to sort this out. Does anyone have any advice/pointers to docs please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile it works: you simply have to **write an email to the PythonAnywhere support** and they will enable it for your account (here are some [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775391/how-to-use-headless-chrome-selenium-on-pythonanywhere)).

Comment: Thanks!  You're quite right, have updated my old answer to say that and to reference yours.

Answer (score 2):

PythonAnywhere dev here -- unfortunately Chrome (headless or otherwise) doesn't work in our virtualization environment right now, so it won't work :-(

[edit] ...but now it does!  See @Ralf Zosel's answer for more details.