# How to use Headless Chrome Selenium on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: selenium, pythonanywhere, google-chrome-headless

["Using Selenium on PythonAnywhere"](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/) says:

> Firefox only, selenium 2, geckodriver not required (…)
> That (Firefox v17.0) is quite an old version, but it
> works for most sites.

In my case it did not work. Is there a way to use Google Chrome (headless) anyway on PythonAnywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this forum entry](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/26870/) with the hint that it is not only possible to use Chrome, but even "You'll need to upgrade Selenium to the most recent version".

I simply wrote an email to the PythonAnywhere support and they enabled that for my (payed) account within hours.

Don't forget to start a new console or restart your web app! Then the following code should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

try:
    browser.get("https://www.google.com")
    print(f'Page title was {browser.title}')

finally:
    browser.quit()
```